# Basis of tensor product

Tags: linear-algebra, tensor-products

Let $V \neq \{0\}$, $W \neq \{0\}$ be vector spaces over a field $K$, $F=(x_i)_{i \in I} \subset V$, $G=(y_j)_{j \in J} \subset W$ systems of vectors. Let $H$ be defined as $H:=(x_i \otimes y_j)_{(i,j) \in I \times J} \subset V \otimes W$.

I want to show that

a) $H$ is linearly independet in $V \otimes W \Leftrightarrow$ $F, G$ are linearly independent

b) $H$ is generating system of $V \otimes W \Leftrightarrow$ $F$ generates $V$, $G$ generates $W$

I got fine with both "$\Leftarrow$", but I'm confused with the "$\Rightarrow$", especially for b). Maybe this is quite obvious and analogue, but how can I conclude that if

$v \otimes w = \sum_{i,j} \lambda_{ij} (x_i \otimes y_j)$ for each $v \otimes w \in V \otimes W$ and some $\lambda_{ij} \in K$, $F$ generates $V$ and $G$ generates $W$? Is it simply possible to write those $\lambda_{ij}$ as a product of some $\alpha_i, \beta_j$?

Comment: You should write $u \in V \otimes W$, not $v \otimes w$, because writing so you implicitly intend that every element is decomposable.

Answer (score 1):

a) Let 
$$
v=\alpha^i x_i=0,\quad w=\beta^j y_j=0,
$$
and build the product
$$
v \otimes w = \alpha^i \beta^j x_i \otimes y_j = 0.
$$
Being $(x_i \otimes y_j)_{(i,j)\in I\times J}$ linearly independent, then
$$
\alpha^i \beta^j = 0\quad\forall i,j \implies \alpha^i=0,\,\forall i,\quad\beta^j=0\,\forall j
$$
so $(x_i)_{i\in I}$ and $(y_j)_{j\in J}$ are linearly independent.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: Tensor products commute with direct sums in each variable.